# pthreads + semaphores, why is this not executing properly?

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads, semaphore

This is an assignment I'm working on. It must use semaphores, not mutex.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <assert.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <semaphore.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
sem_t *ab, *ac, *ad, *de, *ce, *bf, *ef; 

void *a(void *arg) {
    printf("Entering A...\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Exiting A...\n");
    assert(sem_post(ab)==0);
    assert(sem_post(ac)==0);
    assert(sem_post(ad)==0);
    pthread_exit((void *)99);
}

void *b(void *arg) {
    assert(sem_wait(ab)==0);
    printf("Entering B...\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Exiting B...\n");
    assert(sem_post(bf)==0);
    pthread_exit((void *)99);
}

void *c(void *arg) {
    assert(sem_wait(ac)==0);
    printf("Entering C...\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Exiting C...\n");
    assert(sem_post(ce)==0);
    pthread_exit((void *)99);
}

void *d(void *arg) {
    assert(sem_wait(ad)==0);
    printf("Entering D...\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Exiting D...\n");
    assert(sem_post(de)==0);
    pthread_exit((void *)99);
}

void *e(void *arg) {
    assert(sem_wait(ce)==0);
    assert(sem_wait(de)==0);
    printf("Entering E...\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Exiting E...\n");
    assert(sem_post(ef)==0);
    pthread_exit((void *)99);
}

void *f(void *arg) {
    assert(sem_wait(bf)==0);
    assert(sem_wait(ef)==0);
    printf("Entering F...\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Exiting F...\n");
    pthread_exit((void *)99);
}


int main() { 
    pthread_t _a, _b, _c, _d, _e, _f;
    int r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6;

    ab=sem_open("foobar", O_CREAT, 0700, 0);
    ac=sem_open("foobar", O_CREAT, 0700, 0);
    ad=sem_open("foobar", O_CREAT, 0700, 0);
    ce=sem_open("foobar", O_CREAT, 0700, 0);
    de=sem_open("foobar", O_CREAT, 0700, 0);
    ef=sem_open("foobar", O_CREAT, 0700, 0);
    bf=sem_open("foobar", O_CREAT, 0700, 0);

    /*sem_init(ab,0,1);
    sem_init(ac,0,1);
    sem_init(ad,0,1);
    sem_init(ce,0,1);
    sem_init(de,0,1);
    sem_init(ef,0,1);
    sem_init(bf,0,1);*/

    assert(pthread_create(&_a, NULL, a, &r1) == 0);
    assert(pthread_create(&_b, NULL, b, &r2) == 0);
    assert(pthread_create(&_c, NULL, c, &r3) == 0);
    assert(pthread_create(&_d, NULL, d, &r4) == 0);
    assert(pthread_create(&_e, NULL, e, &r5) == 0);
    assert(pthread_create(&_f, NULL, f, &r6) == 0);

    assert(pthread_join(_a, NULL) == 0);
    assert(pthread_join(_b, NULL) == 0);
    assert(pthread_join(_c, NULL) == 0);    
    assert(pthread_join(_d, NULL) == 0);
    assert(pthread_join(_e, NULL) == 0);
    assert(pthread_join(_f, NULL) == 0);

    assert( sem_close(ab)==0 ); 
    assert( sem_close(ac)==0 ); 
    assert( sem_close(ad)==0 ); 
    assert( sem_close(ce)==0 );
    assert( sem_close(de)==0 ); 
    assert( sem_close(bf)==0 );
    assert( sem_close(ef)==0 ); 

    return 0; 
}
```

It's pretty simple but for some reason it's not executing in the right order. The output is far from consistent but always incorrect. Here is one sample output:

Entering A...
Entering B...  <----sem_post(ab) has not even been called yet
Exiting A...
Entering C...
Entering D...
Exiting B...
Exiting D...
Exiting C...
Entering E...
Entering F...
Exiting F...
Exiting E...

It should be following this diagram:

[image]

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated, but it's an assignment so don't start telling me to do it a completely different way and don't give the answer straight up, just point me in the right direction.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using SysV semaphores, rather than pthreads mutexes?

Comment: @bdonlan: These aren't SysV semaphore, they're POSIX semaphores, which are a modern interface that plays nicely with pthreads.  SysV semaphores use `semget()` / `semop()` / `semctl()`.

Comment: I see. Still, why not mutexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code A is not locked before printing the exit line with **ab**.

This means that when it returns from the sleep it can do whatever it wants, because it's not dependent on the lock or anything else.

You should use the semaphores to stop the other thread/functions from continuing. sleep() just gives up the processor the amount of time you specify, after that they can continue.

Note:

You probably don't have to use sleep. the threads will give up the CPU if they can't attain  the lock

Comment: Im a bit unsure what you mean, Id like a deeper explanation if possible

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.  The first is that you only have *one* semaphore, called `foobar`, which you are opening seven times.  The second problem is that named semaphores are persistant - they stay around (and maintain the same value) until you call `sem_unlink()` on them.  Since you never do this, it's likely that the semaphore `foobar` starts with a value greater than zero, from a previous run of your program.

You can correct these problems by using `sem_unlink()` to ensure that the semaphores don't exist before you create them, and using a different name for each semaphore.

Alternatively, you should really be using unnamed semaphores, which are created with `sem_init()` instead of `sem_open()`.  To do this, you would change your declarations of `ab`, `ac`, ... to:

```
sem_t ab, ac, ad, de, ce, bf, ef;
```

You would then change all of the `sem_post()` and `sem_wait()` calls so that they use `&ab`, `&ac`, ...:

```
void *a(void *arg) {
    printf("Entering A...\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Exiting A...\n");
    assert(sem_post(&ab)==0);
    assert(sem_post(&ac)==0);
    assert(sem_post(&ad)==0);
    pthread_exit((void *)99);
}
```

You would replace the `sem_open()` calls with `sem_init()`:

```
sem_init(&ab, 0, 0);
sem_init(&ac, 0, 0);
sem_init(&ad, 0, 0);
sem_init(&ce, 0, 0);
sem_init(&de, 0, 0);
sem_init(&ef, 0, 0);
sem_init(&bf, 0, 0);
```

And finally replace the `sem_close()` calls with `sem_destroy()`:

```
assert( sem_destroy(&ab)==0 );
assert( sem_destroy(&ac)==0 );
assert( sem_destroy(&ad)==0 );
assert( sem_destroy(&ce)==0 );
assert( sem_destroy(&de)==0 );
assert( sem_destroy(&bf)==0 );
assert( sem_destroy(&ef)==0 );
```

---

When I make the changes above to your code, I get the following output, which I believe is what you are expecting:

```
Entering A...
Exiting A...
Entering B...
Entering C...
Entering D...
Exiting B...
Exiting C...
Exiting D...
Entering E...
Exiting E...
Entering F...
Exiting F...
```

Comment: This is a pretty good response, I was confused about that also, but it didnt solve the problem with my program. It still doesn't do what I want it to.

Comment: @Matt: When I make the changes I suggested to your code, it seems to work correctly for me - see output at the end of my updated answer.